# how to make ::selection text background color random from selected colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, random, text

I want to make it so that every time someone highlights text on my sight, the highlight color is different. I have predefined colors that have already been chosen and I will also give you the code I currently have.

My code just runs through each one in a sequence. I need to figure out how to make it so that it will give you a random color from my array.

```
window.colors = [
  "#F78DA7",
  "#CF2E2E",
  "#FF6900",
  "#FCB900",
  "#7BDCB5",
  "#00D084",
  "#8ED1FC",
  "#0693E3",
  "#9B51E0",
];
window.order = 0;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
  document.head.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "<style>::selection { background-color:" +
      window.colors[window.order] +
      "} ::-moz-selection { background-color:" +
      window.colors[window.order] +
      "} ::-o-selection { background-color:" +
      window.colors[window.order] +
      "} ::-ms-selection { background-color:" +
      window.colors[window.order] +
      "} ::-webkit-selection { background-color:" +
      window.colors[window.order] +
      "}</style>"
  );
  window.order = window.order + 1;
  if (window.order > window.colors.length - 1) {
    window.order = 0;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code instead of plus 1:

```js
window.order = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.colors.length);
```

it's will return number between 0 and  window.colors.length - 1

final code should be this

```js
window.colors = ['#F78DA7','#CF2E2E','#FF6900','#FCB900','#7BDCB5','#00D084','#8ED1FC','#0693E3','#9B51E0']
window.order = 0

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<style>::selection { background-color:' + window.colors[window.order] + '} ::-moz-selection { background-color:' + window.colors[window.order] + '} ::-o-selection { background-color:' + window.colors[window.order] + '} ::-ms-selection { background-color:' + window.colors[window.order] + '} ::-webkit-selection { background-color:' + window.colors[window.order] + '}</style>');
window.order = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.colors.length);
```

Comment: Happy to help my friend